# Tantos negativos depois de a pergunta ter sido marcada como pendente?

Tags: debate, voto-contra

Eu percebi que essa pergunta tinha muitos votos negativos (inclusive eu tinha negativado).

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93180/algu%C3%A9m-saberia-fazer-um-sistema-de-vota%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-estrelas

Tinha mais ou menos -5.

Daí passou um tempo percebi que esse usuário tinha -13 votos.

Como percebi que isso era desnecessário, removi o voto negativo.

Será que realmente é necessário tantos votos negativos, depois que o usuário já teve a pergunta marcada como `[pendente]`?

Será que já não é perceptível que existe um defeito na pergunta? Precisa realmente de assustar um usuário que acabou de entrar na comunidade?

Os votos em si não é o problema, mas são muitos votos negativos e poucos comentários para instruir o usuário sobre o tipo de pergunta que deve ser feita!

Comment: Concordo plenamente, -13 era desnecessário, de qualquer forma é o direito de quem vê a pergunta.

Comment: Aquela postagem não é nem uma pergunta, você pode até adicionar ela na sua pergunta.

Comment: A pergunta foi excluida agora.

Comment: Obrigado pela informação @rray

Comment: Com sorte, o usuário não se sente ofendido pessoalmente e aprende alguma coisa sobre o site... depois de tanta gentileza "bem vindo ao site!", "melhore sua pergunta assim ou assado", "por favor, adicione código".... tem um momento que só -1 vezes X passa o recado correto.

Comment: Cada usuário pode votar [up, down, não votar]. Não sei se a quantidade atual de votos deve ser levada em consideração. Cada um pode ponderar como quiser, mas não é uma exigência 'maneirar' depois de uma certa quantidade.

Comment: Lendo a sua pergunta, realmente penso que o sistema dos sites StackExchange **talvez** deveria ter algo que a pergunta fosse quase totalmente bloqueada após ser marcada como "pendente" (incluindo votos) e desbloqueasse após reabrir. -- Mudando um pouco de assunto e falando sobre o usuário em si, ele já tem um tempo de casa sim e não é novo aqui, tanto que eu respondi uma pergunta dele. A questão é ter lido o Help ou não, então no caso dele em si, -13 não vai assusta-lo e se ele se ofendeu o único culpado é ele, pois tem tempo de casa o suficiente, se não se ofendeu então ótimo :)

Comment: Outro detalhe importante, note que ele só vem aqui pra pedir ajuda, código e efeitos e quase nunca ajuda, a unica resposta que tem é na própria pergunta dele http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75528/3635, acho que  a maioria dos negativos foi mais pelo tipo de pessoa que ele é na comunidade do que pela pergunta em si :)

Comment: os negativos talvez sejam de usuários que não tenham permissão de votar para fechar.